# Variable Clustering (varclus) Summary Tables

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, sas

I am using varclus from the Hmisc package in R. Are there ways to produce summary tables from varclus like those is in SAS (e.g. [Output 100.1.2 and Output 100.1.3](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/65328/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_varclus_example01.htm) ) in R. Basically, I would like to know the information that is contained in the plot in a tabular or matrix form. For example: what variables are in what clusters (in SAS *cluster structure*), proportion of variance they explain, etc.

```
# varclust example in R using mtcars data
mtc <- mtcars[,2:8]
mtcn <- data.matrix(mtc)
clust <- varclus(mtcn)
clust
plot(clust)
#cut_tree <- cutree(varclus(mtcn)$hclust, k=5) # This would show group membership, but only after I chose some a cut point, not what I am after
```

Comment: I think you are looking for ClustOfVar package in R. Though I am not familiar enough with the package to give a proper answer.

Comment: This packages has some nice features not readily accessible in hmisc.